# Spaces of Bordered (Ordinary, Spin- or Super-) Riemann Surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, stacks, supermanifolds

It is known from the work of Deligne and Mumford that the "space" of **punctured/marked** Riemann surfaces is a Deligne-Mumford stack. I have few questions regarding similar statement for the spaces of surfaces with borders instead of puncture

- What is the structure of the space of bordered Riemann surfaces? Is it still a stack? Is it a Deligne-Mumford stack?
- What is the structure of the space of bordered spin- or super-Riemann curves? Are they stack? Are they Deligne-Mumford (super)stacks?
- It is said that the space of bordered Riemann surfaces does have a **real** analytic structure but not a **complex structure**. Is this statement correct? How can I see/prove it?

Any reference (except the papers of Mirzakhani) that studies bordered (ordinary, spin- or super-) Riemann surfaces instead of punctured Riemann surfaces is highly appreciated.